# How to distinct query and get last data date? (parse server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-server

like js code
when I do this
it will query up to 1000 times,
can it query once?

```
const promises = idList.map(async id => {
  const query = new Parse.Query("results");
  query.equalTo("id", id);
  query.descending("createdAt");
  query.first()
});
const prPool = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [aggregate](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#aggregate). It would be something like this:

```js
const pipeline = [
  { match: { id: id } },
  { sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
  { group: { objectId: '$id', lastCreatedAt: { $first: '$createdAt' } } }
];
const query = new Parse.Query('results');
const prPool = await query.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: it well show
**"Error: Invalid parameter for query: group. objectId is required"**
the 'id' col is not unique

Comment: I updated my example. I actually don't know exactly your model, but I understood you have a column called id in addition to the default objectId. Anyways it is only an example and you will have to update accordingly. You can also use this reference here: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#aggregate